# LaTeX: newcommand with two arguments

Tags: macros, pdftex

I cannot get this work (please see the code  below):It gives an error"undefined control sequence`\xx` at the line before `\end{document}`. **What's wrong?** I use pdflatex of MikTex under Windows10. It perfectly compiles a bare "Hello world file", so it is installed correctly.
%motivation for the code below:I am a teacher and I need a macro to "correct"errors in my students' papers, as a teacher does in primary school with a red pen, i.e as Word does with its "**Track changes** feature" :The macro should show the "old text"and the "new" corrected text:th Old text should be strikethrough(later I will make it red), the new textshould be hug;eBelow they are denoted as Arg1 and Arg 2.

The question is **NOT** about how to configure miktex or how to use strikethrough or colors --- it is about why is the command \xx still undefined, i.e. why does not `\newcommand` work**:.?
**log file says:**

---

`! Undefined control sequence. l.9 \xx {first}{second}`

**EDIT**:\xvs.\xx is corrected thanks to @David  "\HUGE" command is corrected" thanks to @rafaele, still same error

---

%**LaTeX code**:

```
`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\x}[2]{ARG1:(\st{#1})ARG2: ({\Huge #2})}

\begin{document}


test:
\xx{first}{second}
\end{document}`
```

Comment: You define `\x` but use `\xx`.

Comment: you defined `\x` and used `\xx`

Comment: Use \Huge #2 or \huge #2.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Thank you!  I've changed the commandsto \Huge, still same result: undefined control sequence at line 9.:.log file  says`! Undefined control sequence.
l.9 \xx
       {first}{second}
 
`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes changing to `\newcommand{\xx}` has solved the problemThank you very much!!!Could you please convert your comment to answer? for me to accept it? Oh, so stupid of me! Shame on me! Should I now close the question?, or leave it as answered?

Answer (score 2):

Just a typo in your LaTeX program..

Modify it as follows..

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{soul}
\newcommand{\xx}[2]{ARG1:(\st{#1})ARG2: ({\Huge #2})}

\begin{document}


test:
\xx{first}{second}
\end{document}
```

It works - I tested!

[image: LaTeX Output]

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
\newcommand{\x}[2]{<whatever>}
```

you're defining `\x`, aren't you? So, why would you expect that `\xx` gets defined?

After your

```
\newcommand{\x}[2]{ARG1:(\st{#1})ARG2: ({\Huge #2})}
```

the call

```
\x{first}{second}
```

will do as requested, but of course `\xx` will raise the `Undefined control sequence` error.

The LaTeX kernel has

```
\newcommand{\setlength}[2]{<something irrelevant for the topic here>}
```

and you call it as

```
\setlength{\mylen}{12cm}
```

not `\setlengthsetlength{\mylen}{12cm}`.